# Facing issues with sparse.model.matrix

Tags: r, xgboost

I am trying to enter a data consisting of 30 variables where 10 are factor variables.
I am running xgboost and trying to use sparse.model.matrix function to one hot code the data but there is an error showing up as

> """Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
>     contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels"""
>   Can you let me know how to overcome this error

```
trainm <- sparse.model.matrix(pol ~.-1, data = train)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error is due to a factor with only one level. Please see this example, slightly modified from the doucmentation of `sparse.model.matrix` which is implemented in the `Matrix` package:

```
library(Matrix)    
dd <- data.frame(a = gl(3,4), b = gl(4,1,12), c = gl(1,1, 12))
sparse.model.matrix(~ ., dd)
```

This throws your error, because c is factor with only one level:

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :
```

contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

I do not know about your original data, but something like this could solve it, by throwing away any factor with one level.

```
sparse.model.matrix(~.,dd[,sapply(dd, nlevels) > 1])
```

Comment: So if I remove the variables with one level the code will work properly?

Comment: Yes. At least that is my guess, without knowing your data. You could post a reproducible example, if above does not work for you